# Prority based threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, scjp

I'm studying thread priorities and I have both windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.0 lts operating system.

And I got to know that windows doesn't provide priority based processing so that I can't see the use of priority  based thread programs that how it is actually work .

So I run my priority based program in ubuntu because someone told me that ubuntu provide priority based process.

but when i run my program it show the same output or mixed output as windows.

So is there any way to enable priority in ubuntu ,we can enable priority in windows but for that I should have genuine windows which i haven't.

```
class MyThread extends Threads {
  public void run() {
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+""+i);
    }
   }

class TestThread {
  public static void main(String[] arg){
  Thread.currentThread().setPriority(1);
  MyThread t1=new MyThread();
  t1.setPriority(10);
  t1.start();
  for(int i=0;i<20;i++) 
   system.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+""+i);
 }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with prioritizing certain threads? If you want code to sequentially execute, you might reconsider your program's design. Also, providing some of the hardware's specifications, such as the number of processing cores, might be helpful to those answering the question.

Comment: One more thing: you ask us to spend our time to help you. So you please spend the due diligence and put A) properly formatted/indeted code which does compile (your would not) B) it is called Ubuntu; not Ubantu. C) the other thing that isn't exactly great ... putting up questions; and then turning around and leaving.

Comment: Finally, just because I got curious myself ... I just spent about **a full hour** to code an example that would show the effects of different priorities on Linux. Guess what. I failed. Maybe I continue tomorrow, but the real point here: as I told you; things are **much** harder than you assume they are ;-)

Comment: Thanx @GhostCat at least you understand what i wanted to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, thread *priorities* are more of an **recommendation** towards the JVM.

In other words: each JVM implementation decides for itself how to make use of this concept. So it is not only about Windows vs. Linux; but also about Oracle JVM vs. OpenJDK or IBM JVM; and potentially also about version A of one JVM and some newer version B of that.

And beyond that: be assured that such a (sorry) naive, meaning overly simple piece of example code will **not** help you to figure if your JVM supports priorities or not.

The point is: while system are **not** under heavy load; and there is no shortage of resources ... chances are that even a low priority thread will be able to spit out println statements on the same rate a s high priority thread.

If you are really curious about exploring such things; you will have to put up a more complex example; where your threads are doing some real work; and then you try to add "load" to your system - to then observe if high priority threads can make more progress than low priority ones!